# SharePoint user group cannot access a certain field in a list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, lookup-column

I want a certain group with contribute permission to be able to add and edit items into a list. One of these fields is a lookup value. This seems to cause trouble for the user, since the person cannot click the drop-down-arrow revealing the selections in that field.

This problem seems to only occur for the lookup fields in that list. The person can also not see the look up values for already added items.

I guess this has something to do with the fact that the fields look up to another list. Maybe the person needs the correct permissions for the list that the field does a look up on?

Using SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Do either of these lists have unique permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There are two things you have to take care of:

1. The user/group will need atleast read permission to the Look-up List.
2. The number of look-up columns in your list should ideally be less than 8. If there are more than 8, then you will again end up with issues.